# Error: Selection Based runner not available for Java in Atom

Tags: java, atom-editor

I want to run java in Atom but every time I try to run the program, I get an error saying `Selection Based runner not available for Java`. Now I want to know how to resolve this issue and I also want to know what this line means?

Comment: Why do you think you can compile and execute java from Atom?

Comment: Is it not possible  to run java programs in Atom?

Comment: @MOHITKUMARSINGH Did you try googling the error? [1st link on google](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-run-java-programs-in-atom-editor/30585/8)

Comment: Yes i did...I tried a lot but not getting any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my mistake ....I was not saving my code.I run it after saving and it is running fine.